# Use class property as value in Entity Framework Core Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to use a class within my EF entity and save the value of a property to the DB.

I have an example class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And an Entity Framework Entity like this:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public MyClass Item { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And my context is like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{  
    public MyDbContext()
        : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntity { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                        .Property(x => x.Item.MyProperty)
                        .HasColumnName("NewColumnName");
        }
    }
}
```

All the above is valid in Entity Framework 6 but the same code doesn't work in EF core.

I receive the following error when I try to create a migration:

> The expression 'x => x.Item.MyProperty' is not a valid property
> expression. The expression should represent a simple property access:
> 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'propertyAccessExpression')

So, is what I'm trying to do possible in Entity Framework Core or am I stuck using EF6?

Comment: How is the relation between `MyEntity` and `MyClass` configured?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the column `MyProperty` from `MyClass`, that means that `MyClass` is a table. why would you access that property from a related table `MyEntity`
Try the following code instead:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<**MyClass**>()
        .Property(x => x.**MyProperty**)
        .HasColumnName("NewColumnName");
}
```